# Multidimensional Object array behaviour

Tags: java, arrays, object

I am trying to understand some fundamentals about arrays. I thought multidimensional arrays were really just arrays of arrays. With that in mind, I don't understand the following behavior:

```
Object [] object = {new Object[1]};
Object anotherObject = object[0][0]; //doesn't work
Object yetAnotherObject = object[0]; //does work
```

I am confused why the second line does not compile ("Array type expected"). I thought since "object[0]" was in fact an object array, I could use the square brackets to access its contents.

What am I missing?

Comment: You have a 1-dimensional array. You try to access it like a 2-dimensional array.

Comment: You are defining `object` as a single dim array, but then trying to use it as a 2D array

Answer (score 0):

The type of `object` is `Object[]`, which is a 1 dimensional array. The fact that you store an array element in that array doesn't make it a 2 dimensional array.

```
Object anotherObject = object[0][0];
```

doesn't work since the compiler doesn't know that `object[0]` is an array (and it doesn't have to be - `object[0]` can hold a reference to any `Object`).

You'll need casting in order for it to work:

```
Object anotherObject = ((Object[])(object[0]))[0];
```

Comment: Thanks. I did try casting and got the syntax wrong. This makes sense now.